# Update table where sql in ASP

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to update one field in a table where the id is equal to the selected value by the user. I have accept and reject button and when I press accept it adds YES to the table and NO when I press reject. I seem to have a problem with the query.
This is my code:

```
protected void AcceptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string accepted = "YES";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Journey SET AcceptedJourney = @Accept WHERE JourneyId =  '"+AcceptJourney.SelectedValue+"')");
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accept", accepted);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

        Response.Redirect("~/Account/PassengerDashboard.aspx");
}
```

The error I get is

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: What's the problem with your query? Edit: You have a `)` at the end of your query.

Comment: Im getting an error  Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: why are you using a parameter for Accept but not for JourneyId? It's inconsistent and potentially leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: change `WHERE JourneyId` into `WHERE (JourneyId`

Comment: Im only looking for entries that have JourneyId like the user selected in AcceptedJourney.selectedvalue

Comment: VDWWD was right, I had to add ( beofore JourneyId, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect:

```
"UPDATE Journey SET AcceptedJourney = @Accept WHERE JourneyId =  '"+AcceptJourney.SelectedValue+"')"
```

Correct:

```
"UPDATE Journey SET AcceptedJourney = @Accept WHERE JourneyId =  '"+AcceptJourney.SelectedValue+"';"
```

I have to agree with ADyson though. This will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection. Take a look at the [Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/introduction.aspx) or other options.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Journey SET AcceptedJourney = @Accept WHERE JourneyId =  '"+AcceptJourney.SelectedValue+"';");
```